# Optional parameter in a spread object

Tags: typescript

I have the following definition:

```
interface A {
    new ({a, b?, c});
}
```

It fails compilation due to the optional b parameter:

```
error TS1005: ',' expected.
error TS1180: Property destructuring pattern expected.
```

Removing the ? makes it compile.

How is it possible to express the optional parameter without extracting the spread object into a different type?

Comment: Not when it's in an object. Object keys have no notion of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have doesn't describe the types of `a`, `b`, and `c`.
You should notice they are all typed as `any`.

To specify their type, you need to have the type information, such as

```
interface A {
    new ({a, b, c}: { a: string, b?: string, c: string});
}
```

There's where you can specify `b` is optional.